# Como pegar origem de requisição em asp?

Tags: asp

Estou precisando fazer uma determinada ação com uma página que está em asp clássico.

O que preciso é **pegar a origem da requisição** que é feita nessa página e dependendo de qual a origem, eu faço algo relativo a essa requisição.

Por exemplo, se a requisição for advinda da própria página no asp, eu deixo o fluxo correr normalmente. Mas se a requisição tiver outra origem(o postman e o burp suite fazem isso) aí eu trataria a situação de outra maneira.

A intenção é cuidar da segurança do sistema.

Como posso capturar a origem dessa requisição no asp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`HTTP_REFERER` não garante segurança nenhuma**, é muito fácil sobrescreve-lo e fraudar a origem já que se trata de um *header*.

O melhor a se fazer em questão para garantir a origem do formulário poderia ser usando o [**reCAPTCHA**](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/)

Também experimentar técnicas como proteção *anti-CSRF* (*CSRF* significa *Cross-Site Request Forgery*), não é 100% eficiente, mas funciona melhor que `HTTP_REFERER`, um exemplo do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6446967/1518921) (eu só não sei se md5 é realmente algo necessário)

Creio que seria algo como:

- **Todas páginas** que receberem requisição ou tiverem um Form ou um Ajax devem (pode colocar no global ou em uma função):

  ```vb
  Function GetGUID()

      GetGUID = CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").GUID

  End Function

  Dim token

  ' Só atualiza o valor da sessão se não vier de um POST
  ' com `<input name=csrftoken>`
  If Request.Form("csrftoken") = "" Then
      token = md5(GetGUID())
      Session("token")=token
      Session("token_time")=Time()
  End If
  ```
- Na página que receber o POST/requisição deve ter isso:

  ```vb
  If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST" Then
      ' Compara o Form com a sessão
      If Request.Form("csrftoken") = Session("token") Then
          ' Executa o seu código aqui !!!
      End If
  End If
  ```
- No form você também deve adicionar o `Session("token")`

  ```html
  <form method="post" action="pagina.asp">
      <input type="text" name="foo" placeholder="Exemplo">
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
      <input type="hidden" value="<%= Session("token") %>" name="csrftoken">
  </form>
  ```

> Faz muito tempo que não trabalho com asp clássico, se tiver qualquer erro de digitação estão livres para corrigi-los

### Como enganar o Referer e Origin

Com [**Postman**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) ou [**Wget**](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) é fácil enganar o site, veja basta jogar isso no terminal (ser for Linux, apesar de ser possível instalar em Windows):

```
wget 
--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
--header="Host: seusite.com"
--header="Origin: http://seusite.com"
--header="Referer: http://seusite.com/pasta/formulario.asp" 
--header="Connection: keep-alive"
--header="Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5"
--post-data="campo1=foo&campo2=bar"
http://seusite.com/pasta/pagina.asp
```

Pronto, eu enganei o teu sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o que você precisa seja `referer = Request.ServerVariables ("HTTP_REFERER")`, segue um link com todas as opções do [ServerVariables](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp).

Só informando que o HTTP_REFERER não funciona em todos os casos, caso venha de um redirect por exemplo, ele não pega esse valor.